# view table joins in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables a category table and a factory table.
in my category table i have the following rows.

```
idcategory
category
```

In my factory table i have the following rows.

```
idfactories
factoryname
postcode
country
telephone number
email
website
profile
adress
idcategory
```

i have another table where i have the idfactory and idcategory stored too.

my factorycategories table has the following rows.

```
idfactorycat
idfactory
idcategory
factorycat
```

i made a join in my category model because i want to the categories on my site and when i click on a category the factories who are stored in that category has to show up.

in my model i have

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('bedrijfcategorieen');
$this->db->join('bedrijfcategorieen', 'bedrijfcategorieen.idbedrijven = bedrijven.idbedrijven');
$this->db->join('bedrijfcategorieen', 'bedrijfcategorieen.idcategorieen = categorieen.idcategorieen');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

what do i actually have to store in my controller and views?
i am very new to codeigniter.

ps: i translated my rows so it is easy to understand for others because i am dutch.

Thanks

EDIT:
it's a bit tricky to explain but i have a sidebar catogories.

```
Categories

cars
cars parts
books
etc etc...
```

i want to create links from each category.

when click on, let's say cars. i want to go to a results page where are factories showed up who have a category id=1 because cars has an id=1.
this was my actual question. and i think i need join for that.

Hope you understand it.

thanks again.

Comment: Well, it's a bit like asking too much but I'd update my answer to accomodate your edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit to match your edit

Based on your Edit, I'm just giving you the basic ideas here. Please refer to the codeigniter manual for details:

//Model

```
function getresults($segment3){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('category');
    $this->db->join('factories', 'category.idcategory. ' = factories.idfactories');
    $this->db->join('factorycategories', 'factorycategories.idfactory = ' . $segment3); 

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}

//Note that it would return only results that match in all tables. 
//If you need to return more of a table, use right join or left join.


function categories(){ //Call this from controller to create the initial links
    $query = $this->db->get('category');
    return $query->result();
}
```

//Controller

```
function pageCategories(){ // Shows initial categories links on page
    $data["links"] = $this->modelname->categories();
    $this->load->view("page-to-view");
}

function pageFactories(){ // takes categories and shows factories
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $segment3 = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $data["results"] = $this->modelname->getresults($segment3);  
    $this->load->view("page-to-view");
}
```

//View

```
print_r($results); //run a test - debug
```

Show your Links (Note the segment pattern):

```
if(isset($links) && is_array($links)){
    foreach($links as $k => $value){
        echo '<a href="'.base_url().'Yourcontroller/pageFactories/'.$value->idcategory.' ">' .$value->category. '</a>';
        echo "<br />";
    }
}

if(isset($results ) && is_array($results )){
    foreach($results as $key => $row){
        echo $row->category;
        echo "<br />";
        echo $row->factoryname;
        //It goes on as much as you want
    }
}
```

#### This is just so you get the big picture.

How you'd convert that back to Dutch is what I can't figure out. Note: google.translate.com would mess it up with lots of white spaces you might have to clean up.

Comment: i can translate it back to dutch myself so that's no problem. this looks nice i will try this thanks :)

Comment: i can't really get it to work. and maybe you guys understand me wrong. i have a sidebar where i view my categories. that works fine. but then i want to link them to another page so when clicked i show te categories who have that category id.

Comment: editted my question a bit. under the EDIT: please look at it.

Comment: Allright it worked out with a few changes in your code. thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to know, thought it would have taken a while, can I know the changes you had to make? I was typing directly into stackoverflow textarea. Strange thing to do, but it seems kind of tough doing it that way. Must have missed a thing or two.

Comment: oh you editted the post i see now. the join worked. i can now view all the id's from the tables. now i can implement the links as you wrote above. thanks.

Comment: I was wondering. Thanks too. Nice way for you to translate Dutch to English beautifully

Comment: i have one little question left. i implemented te code but i can't view the factories in my categories. it links to http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl//home/pagebedrijven/$value-%3E$idcategorieen so i think the last part does not work. i also get the error Message: Undefined variable: segment3

Comment: I guess you understand codeigniter url. You have to pass the idcategory in the link to your url which would be retrieved by this `$segment3 = $this->uri->segment(3);`. Note that you are going to use id=2&etc. You url is missing segment(3). This where you form the url `echo '<a href="'.base_url().'/Yourcontroller/pageFactories/$value->idcategory ">' .$value->category. '</a>';` Make sure you translations is accurate. There are a few things you'd have to modify and specify. like you could be using categoryid while my example is idcategory

Comment: i have it with my translation: echo '<a href="'.base_url().'/home/pagebedrijven/$value->idcategorieen ">' .$value->Categorie. '</a>'; do i miss something? because it get the url like i posted.

Comment: Let's switch over to chat, so I know what your problem really is. Could you do a chat with English? or translate as you go?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25541/discussion-between-kees-sonnema-and-steward-godwin-jornsen)

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a general MVC question. Your database schema is not important for this question since you're wondering how to access the data and not how to optimize your query (from what I understood)...

So your model needs to return something, like `return $query->result();`. Then you could use that in your controller to get that data and send it to a view. For example:

Controller

```
$data['my_data'] = $this->my_model->my_get_function();  // this is calling your function above
$this->load->view('my_view', $data);  // loads my_view and sends the data array to it
```

In the view you keep all the presentional (HTML) data, but you have the access to the data you sent by the controller, in our case that would be `$my_data` which is an object consisting of all the returned rows from the query you made. This will show you that data:

View

```
// ...html here...
<div>
    <pre>
        <?php var_dump($my_data); ?>
    </pre>
</div>
// ...html here...
```

These are just example parts of controllers and views. Read more about MVC to get a better idea on how it's supposed to work.

Comment: Yeah but i'm wondering too if my model is right. because i am very new to codeigniter

Comment: but i will look at it and try.

Comment: It looks alright, you just need to wrap it into a method/function (I used `my_get_function` for the function name and `my_model` for the model name in the example above.

Comment: i've tried it and when i do a var_dump i only get the categories. that gives the same output as when i do a simple $this->db->get('categories'); return $query->result(); so that's strange

Comment: You're joining to the same table. The first parameter in the join method is the new table you're joining the old one with. Maybe you also need to use LEFT joins then... for example: `$this->db->join('bedrijven', 'bedrijfcategorieen.idbedrijven = bedrijven.idbedrijven', 'left');`

Comment: what does that do instead of a normal join? i want to have links for each category on my site and store factories in a specific category so when i click a category, some factories has to show up on the page.

Comment: In short: your 'from' table and each of the 'join' tables must be different in order for it to make sense.

Comment: If you have the sql query ready and working, you don't have to use CI's active records, but just use your query like this: `$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM factories...');`

Comment: do i have to do this in mysql too? or only in codeigniter model.

Comment: What do you mean in mysql too? You can test the query in mysql, and then use it in the model.

Comment: ah oke i got it. thanks :) i will try this but the whole idea isn't very clear yet.

Comment: No problem, take your time, read the [CI docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/), you have a lot of info there... And don't forget to select the answer if it helped you. :)